# How to sort data in Excel to have the same mean?

Tags: excel, sorting

I've a set of data in excel that i need to sort to reach the closest mean between columns in excel:

[image]

I need to sort (obviousliy mixing) the data to have columns of six datas but with the closest mean possible between them.

| DATA | VALUE |  | DATA | VALUE |  | DATA | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| B4 | 9 |  | B1 | 32 |  | C1 | 3 |
| A2 | 5 |  | B2 | 5 |  | C2 | 2 |
| B3 | 56 |  | C6 | 7 |  | C3 | 155 |
| A4 | 5 |  | C5 | 56 |  | B5 | 3 |
| A5 | 79 |  | C4 | 6 |  | A1 | 1 |
| A6 | 5 |  | B6 | 45 |  | A3 | 4 |
|  | 26,5 |  |  | 25,16667 |  |  | 28 |

Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide an example of the expected output - to me it is not clear how this should look like. And it is easier for us to help you, if you provide sample data (and expected output) as table within your question - e.g. use [Markdown Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables)

Comment: | DATA | VALUE |   | DATA | VALUE    |   | DATA | VALUE |
| B4   | 9     |   | B1   | 32       |   | C1   | 3     |
| A2   | 5     |   | B2   | 5        |   | C2   | 2     |
| B3   | 56    |   | C6   | 7        |   | C3   | 155   |
| A4   | 5     |   | C5   | 56       |   | B5   | 3     |
| A5   | 79    |   | C4   | 6        |   | A1   | 1     |
| A6   | 5     |   | B6   | 45       |   | A3   | 4     |
|      | 26,5  |   |      | 25,16667 |   |      | 28    | 
Something like that as results. I need to rearrange the data to have columns with similar means.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the data - and it would help if you show an expected result table as well - "sth like that" is not precise enough ...

Comment: Nothing in the proposed output appears to be sorted in any way.

Comment: I think what you're really trying to do is rearrange the elements in the table (no constraints -- any element can go to any column) such that the total of each column is as close as possible. This is the [3-way balanced partition problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balanced_number_partitioning#Balanced_partitioning_with_larger_cardinalities). Fortunately, [someone wrote a paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01193837). Unfortunately, it's NP-hard.

Comment: No wait, that's not what you did. Because 235 magically changed to 155!